# Get Name and DHCP status By Powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, cmd

could you help me with, i'm trying to get the computer name and the output from this command below in a txt file.

for /f %1 in (user_plant.txt) do >>\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\nic.txt ((wmic /node:%i computersystem get caption | more) & (powershell -command "& {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName %i. | Format-Table -Property IPAddress, DHCPEnabled}))

the command powershell when i run without the rest, it's works fine, but when i try to put together not work.

userplant.txt has:
brspd001
brspd002 
...

My needly is: A txt file with Name of machine and IPV4,DHCP status as the same showed when i run only the powershell command.
example:

Computername:
BRSPD001 
IP
172 ... 
DHCP Enabled
true.

or someone like it.

could you help me?

Comment: You are using `%i` in your command, but `%1` as the index to your `for` loop - is this a typo, and your intent to use `%i`? Also, does `user_plant.txt` contain the list of computers you want this for? Please edit your question to include some sample input and output.

Comment: Done Jeff as you request.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better done in pure PowerShell. Assuming one computername per line in user_plant.txt:

```
foreach ($Computer in (Get-Content -Path user_plant.txt)) {
    $c = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = $true"
    "ComputerName: {0}  IP: {1}  DHCPEnabled {2}" -f $Computer,$C.IPAddress[0],$C.DHCPEnabled | Add-Content -Path "\\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\nic.txt"
}
```

Comment: i need it create a txt file and sent to \\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\nic.txt.

Comment: Edited; see above - but note that it's only one way of doing it; there are others. I really recommend that you do a bit more studying of PowerShell; you could have discerned this on your own rather easily.